# Extensions of probability measures on fields

Tags: pr.probability

I know this may be a trivial question for this forum, but I already posted on mathexchange and I did not get an answer to my doubts.

I am trying to solve exercise 3.3 in Billingsley's "Probability and measure" and I am not sure if I correctly understood the text. I am not going to copy all the text, but I will ask directly some questions.

Some background:

Let $\mathbb P$ be a probability measure on the field $\mathcal F_0$ and $\mathbb P^*$ be the outer measure defined for each subset $A$ of $\Omega$ as $\mathbb P^*(A)=\inf \sum_n \mathbb P(A_n)$, where $A \subset \cup_n A_n$.
A theorem (3.1 in Billingsley) guarantees that $\mathbb P^*$ is the unique probability measure on the $\sigma$-field $\sigma(\mathcal F_0)$ such that $\mathbb P^*(B)=\mathbb P(B)$ for each $B \in\mathcal F_0$.

Now the questions:

> 1) If $\Omega$ is uncountable and $\mathcal F_0$ is the field of finite and cofinite sets, and $\mathbb P(A)=0$ if $A$ is finite and $\mathbb P(A)=1$ if $A$ is cofinite, do $\mathbb P^*$ (defined as above) and $\mathbb P$ agree on $\mathcal F_0$?

My answer: $\mathbb P$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal F_0$ (it is possible to check that it is countably additive) and then theorem 3.1 holds and $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb P^*$ agree on $\mathcal F_0$.
My doubt comes from the fact that the text of the exercise seems to suggest that this is not the case and to explain why...

> 2) If $\Omega$ is uncountable and $F_0$ is the field of countable and cocountable  sets, and $\mathbb P(A)=0$ if $A$ is countable and $\mathbb P(A)=1$ if $A$ is cocountable, do $\mathbb P^*$ (defined as above) and $\mathbb P$ agree on $\mathcal F_0$?

My answer would be the same than before:
$\mathbb P$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal F_0$ (it is possible to check that it is countably additive) and then theorem 3.1 holds and $\mathbb P^*$ agree on $F_0$.

> 3) Let $\mathbb P(A)=I_A(\omega_0)$ for $A \in \mathcal F_0$, and assume that ${\omega_0} \in \sigma(\mathcal F_0)$, do $\mathbb P^*$ (defined as above) and $\mathbb P$ agree on $\mathcal F_0$?

My answer would be the same than before:
$\mathbb P$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal F_0$ (it is possible to check that it is countably additive) and then theorem 3.1 holds and $\mathbb P^*$ agree on $\mathcal F_0$.
In this case I do not understand also why the text specifies that ${\omega_0} \in \sigma(\mathcal F_0)$.